# Why object of number can be added in TreeSet

Tags: java, collections, wrapper, comparable

The object of class which we want to add into TreeSet, that Class must implement Comparable interface
But Number class does not implement Comparable then how TreeSet allow Number to get added.

```
    Number n1= 11;
    Number n2= 12;
    Number n3= 13;
    Set<Number> set = new TreeSet<>();
    set.add(n1);
    set.add(n2);
    set.add(n3);
```

Comment: TreeSet doesn't require that it's generic elements be `Comparable`'s.

Comment: Why do you think that elements of a Collection need to implement the Comparable interface?

Comment: I tried same program with a class T (which doesn't implement the Comparable interface), in TreeSet, which is throwing java.lang.ClassCastException.
But In above program, I have used Number which does not implement Comparable interface still it is working fine.

Both things are contradictory.
In one scenarios it is working with a class which doesn't implements Comparable interface, but in other case it is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right

> Class must implement Comparable interface.

And here in your example the above statement is valid. Number has child class Integer and when we do this:

```
 Number n1= 11;
```

On runtime it create Integer object and Integer implement the Comparable.

You can also see this in java doc. [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/package-tree.html)

OR
We can also proof with program like this:

```
Number n1 = 10;
System.out.println(n1 instanceof Number);   //true  
System.out.println(n1 instanceof Integer);  //true  
System.out.println(n1 instanceof Comparable);   //true
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Thanks @Learner. Now I understand
so when we create object using 
Number n1 =11;
It actually creates object of Integer. and Interger class Implements Comparable interface

Answer (score 1):

Your code compiles without errors because the requirement that the elements of a `Treeset` implement `Comparable` is NOT enforced by static typing.

Two reasons:

1. That (hypothetical) type constraint does not exist in the `Set<T>` interface, so `Set<Number>` is perfectly valid.
2. Not all use-cases for TreeSet require this; e.g. `TreeSet` instances that are instantiated with a `Comparator` don't require that the elements implement `Comparable`.  Hence, the type constraint does not exist on the `TreeSet` type parameter either.  (Check the javadocs!)

Anyhow, the restriction is implemented by a runtime check, not by compile-time typing.

---

As @learner points out, you code will actually run.  That is because your `Number` objects are actually `Integer` instances, and `Integer` implements `Comparable<Integer>`.